# EnvoyFilter jwt_authn didn't send request to etension service in istio1.9

Tags: jwt, istio, envoyproxy

I'm trying to configure a custom authentication behavior in istio1.9: While a request coming with an expired but valid JWT, there is a special service would automatically refresh jwt.
I'm trying to use Envoy Filter to do this, so I'd created an envoyfilter with configuration below:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: refresh-token-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            subFilter:
              name: envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
        name: envoy.filters.http.ext_authz
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.ext_authz.v2.ExtAuthz
          http_service:
            server_uri:
              uri: http://token-mng-service.auth.svc.cluster.local:8000
              cluster: outbound|8000||token-mng-service.auth.svc.cluster.local
              timeout: 1s
            authorizationRequest:
              allowedHeaders:
                patterns:
                - exact: authorization
            authorizationResponse:
              allowedUpstreamHeaders:
                patterns:
                - exact: username
                - exact: id_token
              allowedClientHeaders:
                patterns:
                - exact: id_token
```

I hoped that every request would be sent to a service named token-mng-service in namespace auth which would refresh expired token then response back with a header names id_token.
token-mng-service was configured as below:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: token-mng-deployment-v1
  namespace: auth
  labels:
    app: token-mng
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: token-mng
      version: v1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: token-mng
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: token-mng
          image: token_mng:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: token-mng-service
  namespace: auth
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
    name: http
  selector:
    app: token-mng
```

Also, I had create a RequestAuthentication as below:

```
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "RequestAuthentication"
metadata:
  name: authtest
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "https://192.168.50.113:30443/oauth2/token"
    jwksUri: "http://192.168.50.113:30443/oauth2/jwks"
```

But, there is no request had been sent to my tokne-mng-service. Is there any wrong in my configuration?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing here but check filter order in generated Envoy configuration. If JWT filter is first it will detect expired token and result in 401 before ext auth filter has a chance to refresh it.